# Whether to pass shared pointer or raw pointer to a function

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, memory

### Situation

Some third-party API I use works with raw pointers, but I have smart pointers all over my client code.

### Problem

When I want to write a wrapper function around the API, I face a problem: Whether to pass shared pointers or their raw pointers underneath as arguments.

Like this:

The smart pointer version

```cpp
// my wrapper

void MyWrapper(const std::shared_ptr<MyClassA>& pInObj, std::shared_ptr<MyClassB>& out_pOutObj) {

    ThirdParty_DoStuff(pInObj.get(), out_pOutObj.get());
}

// my client code

auto inObj = std::make_shared<MyClassA>();
auto outObj = std::make_shared<MyClassB>();

MyWrapper(inObj, outObj);
```

The raw pointer version

```cpp
// wrapper

void MyWrapper(MyClassA* pInObj, MyClassB* out_pOutObj) {

    assert(pInObj && out_pOutObj);
    ThirdParty_DoStuff(pInObj, out_pOutObj);
}

// client code

auto inObj = std::make_shared<MyClassA>();
auto outObj = std::make_shared<MyClassB>();

MyWrapper(inObj.get(), outObj.get());
```

### Question

- Which is the better approach in terms of performance and memory safety?
- Will the reference counting work slightly differently between both approaches?

I think that the second version is more reusable if one day the function must work with other kinds of memory management.

Comment: If the function has something to do with *ownership* of your object, it should accept a shared pointer. If not, accept a raw pointer or a reference.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That advice only works if smart pointers aren’t (ab)used as business objects, and it seems that that’s the case in OP’s code — “I have smart pointers all over my client code”. In that case, passing the business object (i.e. the smart pointer) seems the cleaner approach. A better approach would be to have the client code handle properly encapsulated objects rather than `std::shared_ptr`s.

Comment: If you will pass `const std::shared_ptr<>&`, then there is no difference from performance point of view. Reference counting works exactly same, since counter will not be increased. But if you will pass `std::shared_ptr` by value, then there will be difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach to looking at code something like this:

[image]

*There are some other options like `weak_ptr`, but for this it is probably not worth looking at.*

So for your example, we can see that `ThirdParty_DoStuff` does not take ownership, so we won't either, so you can choose between a reference and a pointer depending on if the argument is mandatory or not respectively.

**EDIT:**
As of c++17, you have the option of using `optional` This can also now cover the case where you have an optional output.

Comment: @kakyo, nice! doing some cleanup of the `Third` typo. I am happy that you are putting effort into making this a good Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using references/raw pointers depending if you want to pass `nullptr` or not. Why? It is a good guideline to pass as little as required - if you do not need increasing reference count or do anything specific with `shared_ptr` passing it is not required and may be misleading.

About your questions - both are rather safe IF the wrapped API can handle `nullptr`. If not (and this is suggested by your `assert`), references will be safer.

The reference counting will work same way for all of the approaches since you pass by reference. Should you passed by value it would increase reference count for the call of function.

All in all, my suggested solution:

```
// wrapper

void MyWrapper(MyClassA& pInObj, MyClassB& out_pOutObj) {

    ThirdParty_DoStuff(&pInObj, &out_pOutObj);
}

// client code

auto inObj = std::make_shared<MyClassA>();
auto outObj = std::make_shared<MyClassB>();

MyWrapper(*inObj, *outObj);
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice suggestion regarding my clue with the assertion.